# Custom Dialog using DialogFragment

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-dialogfragment

I just recently am trying to convert an app that uses a ProgressDialog that extends DialogFragment, not Dialog.

How can you

1. Create a Custom Dialog Class extending DialogFragment
2. Then load the dialog by calling this class from Activity

Can I see a super basic example? What methods to override? And what about the constructor?

Right now this is what I am doing (the old way):

```
private MyProgressDialog progressDialog = new MyProgressDialog(
                    getActivity());
progressdialog.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a progress dialog ***fragment***?

It's actually really simple. DialogFragments are just Fragments that wrap around a dialog, so you just need to create your dialog as usual in the onCreateDialog method of the DialogFragment.

e.g.

```
class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

And to show the DialogFragment:

```
mButton = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new ProgressDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "MyProgressDialog");
    }
});
```